# Using multiple SpriteBatches in different levels of an XNA game causing components to remain Inivisible

Tags: xna, sprite, composite, drawablegamecomponent

I am currently trying to add Screens logic to my XNA-based space invaders game.

My problem is :

Each screen manages it's own game components (SpaceShip, EnemyMatrix etc)  with the help of a CompositeDrawableComponent instance, used as a GameComponentsManager.

Each game component contains additional game components within it self (i.e. SpaceShip holding a Bullet) and so contains a GameComponentsManager instance of it's own.

Each GameComponentsManager contains a SpriteBatch for all of it's components, i.e. PlayScreen uses a unique SpriteBatch for it's SpaceShips, and each SpaceShip uses a unique SpriteBatch for it's bullets.

As a result, the SpaceShip's components are simply drawn behind the Screen's components (in my case, the background) and remain invisible to the user.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Too easy to be the answer, but have you tried drawing first the screen spritebatch, then the rest? This has the problem that the level cannot have clouds or similar appearing over the ships, but if you want to keep using multiple batches...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple SpriteBatches.

You can still keep all your SpriteBatch variables within all your classes, but instead of declaring a new one each time, pass one single one around. All you'll have to change at this point is to make sure you're only Beginning and Ending one time, and now you can have better control of the draw order. You can either use the layer depth or just manually draw in the right order.

Comment: Hey Scott, I understand your single Batch attitude, yet the code I am required to use (with in the CompositeDrawableComponent class for instance) rather forces me to use multiple batches for each of the components. I've been trying to look for a combination of parameters I can send to Begin(params) which might solve my problem but until now, no success. @Scott W

Comment: I'm confused how you're forced to use multiple? Could you post some code to demonstrate this?